# date picker on ruby

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, intellij-idea, datepicker

i am trying to add datepicker to my web page using ruby on rails. i got the calendar displayed when i click in the textbox but when i choose a date its not inserted in the textbox.

this is the textbox view:

```
<div class="field" data-behaviour='datepicker'>
            <%= label_tag :"availability"  %><br>
            <%= text_field_tag :availability ,  @current_user.availability %>
```

i already added confijurations to application.js and applications.css and views/layout/application.html.erb.

any idea how to solve that?

Comment: what js/css framework are you using? bootstrap? foundation? you have to update the tags so you get more relevant users to help you answer your question.

Comment: im using 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails', and im using intellij with ruby plugin.